# C# クラス型配列変数の初期化について

Tags: c#, array, unity2d

はじめまして、一昨日からC#をやり始めました初心者です。

参考書で、クラス型配列変数の初期化について書かれていたのですが

```
void Start() {
  Person[] parr = { new Person(), new Person() };
  parr[0].firstname = "太郎";
  parr[0].lastname = "山田";
  Debug.Log (parr[0].GetFullName("★"));
}
```

となっており、２行目のnew Person ()を何故２つ書いているのかがわかりません。

`Person[] parr = { new Person() };`

でも同様の結果となったのでますます混乱しています。
わかる方がいらっしゃったらご教授頂きたいです、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: １つ目が配列変数のインスタンスを作っているのか？なら、２つめはなんだろう？となっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

配列初期化子は指定した値の数と同じ長さの配列を作成し、各値を先頭から順に設定していきます。
ですので値を1個しか書かなかった場合は2番目の要素`parr[1]`にアクセスすることができず、例外が発生します。また`parr.Length`も当然変化します。

なお`parr[0]`と`parr[1]`は同じ`new Person()`が指定されていますが、参照型では別のオブジェクトになります。

参考書でなぜ先頭しか使っていないのかはわかりません。配列の使用例としては不適切に思えます。

Answer (score 0):

> ２行目のnew Person ()を何故２つ書いているのかがわかりません。

尤もな疑問です。これを入門書でやられると素直な学習の妨げにもなりかねないと思います。
私がレビュアーなら、このような意図の不明な記述は承認できません。

推測ですが、元々は3行目以降で `parr[1]` にアクセスするような意味のあるコードが記述されていたが、その後の手直しを繰り返すうちに削られてしまったのかも知れません。

> クラス型配列変数の初期化について

がその項のテーマであれば、私なら以下のように書きます。

```
void Start() {
    string[] names = { "山田", "佐藤" };
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
    }
}
```

余計なお世話かと思いますが、入門書は広く支持されている実績のあるものを選ばれた方が良いかと思います（今の時代、ネットにも良くまとめられた Web サイトもあります）。

Comment: 配列自体の `new` だけでなくて、配列の要素の `new` も必要であることを明示しておきたいので当該参考書は new を明示してるんだろうと思うのです。 `string` はリテラル書いちゃうと `new` 不要で、しかも immutable なのが既に納得できる人なら適切なのかな・・・とか思ったり。配列の要素 `[1]` にちゃんとアクセスしているなら良かったわけですが。

Comment: 解りやすい書き方は、ある意味哲学かもしれませんね。個人的には、初学者ほどテーマは絞って例示してあげたほうが、注視すべき箇所・考えるべき事がシンプルになって、迷い無く取り組めるのではないかと考えています。今回の場合、あくまでも`クラス方配列変数の初期化`がテーマなのだと捉えると、`new` による型のインスタンス化やオブジェクトの内部状態の変更（e.g. `parr[0].firstname = "太郎";`）は別項で取り上げた方が平易かな、と思った次第です。